# How to test the current input text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to test if the answer text is matching with the word that was declared in a object. But i can't test the current word because when i click i want first to test if the answer is correct but the variable is not already declared

here is my function onClick

```
function testerField() {
    
    // I'd like to test if the user's answer properly
    // match the word before shuffling
    

    var test = document.getElementById('wordfinal').value;
    
    // random func
    var random = getRandomInt(listeWord.length)
    
    // get the word from js object
    var stock = listeWord[random].word
    
    // shuffle the word
    var afficher = stock.shuffle()

    // display
    document.getElementById('word').value = afficher;
    
}
```

here is my list

```
const listeWord = [
    {
        id: 1,
        word: 'escalope',
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        word: 'canapé'
    },

    {
        id: 3,
        word: 'table',
    },

    {
        id: 4,
        word: 'télé'
    }
]
```

here is my html code

```html
<div class="main_content">
        <form onsubmit="submitPrevent(event)">
            <p class="phraseForm">Find the Word</p>
            <input type="integer" class="formInt" id="word" >
            <p class="phraseForm">Word</p>
            <input type="integer" class="formInt" id="wordfinal" >
            

            <div id="sub">
                <input type="submit" value='Ok' class="envoyer" onclick="testerField()">
            </div>
```

Comment: Did you define `getRandomInt` somewhere in your code (or did you get it from an external library)? If you typed out the function, can you please **share it** (or if you got it from an external library, then share the name of the library)?

Comment: Also, did you get the `shuffle` method from an external library (or added it in the `String.prototype`)? As far as I know, there isn't a built-in `shuffle` method in native Vanilla JavaScript for a `string`.